# How to use ls() correctly in specified environment?

Tags: r, environment

OK, I'm feeling stupid this AM. Consider:

```
ppenv<-new.env(parent=.GlobalEnv)
assign('.dirhist','/Users/cgw/Rgames',ppenv)
ls(envir=ppenv)
character(0)
 exists('.dirhist',envir=ppenv)
[1] TRUE
 get('.dirhist',envir=ppenv)
[1] "/Users/cgw/Rgames"
```

So my question is: how do I determine the contents of my environment `ppenv` , i.e. what objects exist there?

Comment: I've found that `with(e, ls())` works nicely as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is due to the object name beginning with a `.`. Use the argument `all.names = TRUE`:

```
ls(envir = ppenv, all.names = TRUE)
```

From the help page of `ls`:

> **all.names** 
>   a logical value. If TRUE, all object names are returned. If FALSE, names which begin with a . are omitted.

Comment: Thanks, like I said -- I was feeling stupid and you certainly verified my statement :-)

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I do not consider this as a verification of your statement. ;-)